# Border moving with hover

Tags: css, hover, border

I have two links in a nav bar that need to sit perfectly centered and 50/50 on the page. That part I struggled with but finally got them to sit right. I needed a grey bottom border to span the entire page and when you hover the grey under the links needed to turn blue. Here's an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jELbb.png)

Here's what i have for the html:

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <a class="accommodations" href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
    <a class="activities" href="#activities"> Activities </a>
</div>
```

Here's what I have for the mobile css:

```
.topnav {
    padding-top: 17px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #808080;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    border-top: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.topnav a {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 17px;
    border-top: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    padding-top: 17px;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #0065fc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

When I add the hover affect it does have the blue bar however, instead of covering the grey it appears on top and seems to push the grey bar down. On the desktop dimensions the hover has to appear at the top with a space between the words and the bar which is why I have the padding on the top. Without it the words move when you hover over them.

I've tried adjusting/adding/removing the padding on the bottom, adding a border bottom to the individual elements rather than the whole, and even played with negative margins just to see if by some miracle it made this problem go away. It does sort of work with adding a border bottom to the individual elements but the border doesn't span the entire page and instead stops just after activities with this weird gap on the right.

I would also like to add that I have maybe a months worth of experience with coding, and by experience i mean trial by fire and no direct teacher so everything I know is from various books, googling, and free coding camps. I am probably doing something very obviously wrong and I apologize but any help would be greatly appreciated because I can tell you begging it to work hasn't helped yet.

--update--
okay so i found that if i remove the border from the .topnav and instead put it on the individual the hover works the way I want it to however i'm still running into the issue of the border not spanning the entire page and instead having the weird space on the right side after activities.

---update#2--
You all are freaking amazing! Thank you so much I used everyone's notes and recommendations and it is finally doing what I want it to do with no issues, errors, or warnings!

Comment: I’m looking at your question after the update 2 hours ago. Can you make your code into a runnable snippet that reproduces the space on the right problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Declare `border-bottom` for `a` instead of `.topnav` and then change the color on hover.

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav a {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #808080;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #0065fc;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="accommodations" href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
  <a class="activities" href="#activities"> Activities </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.
For your css style

```
  .nav-container {
    border-bottom: solid 3px #808080;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .topnav {
    padding-top: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1200px; /* You can remove this part if you need full width */
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    border-top: none;
  }

  .topnav a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 3px #0065fc;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
  }
```

For your HTML

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="accommodations" href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
    <a class="activities" href="#activities"> Activities </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using grid, then having  elements take up the space available to them. Have a border on each and just change its appearance on hover.

Your .topnav element should probably be a `<nav>` rather than a div, and I've changed that here. It's also common to have navigation menu items in a list and just styled to look otherwise, but I've not changed that.

Demo code with comments:

```css
.topnav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(max-content, 1fr)); /* 2 columns with same settings - miminum size of the column is the text's width, maximumm size at 1fr means take up the remaining space available */
  gap: 0; /* We don't want a gap between elements as we want a consistent border look */
}

.topnav a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red; /* Set a 'default' border */
  width: 100%; /* Make the <a> take up the width it's allowed to */
  text-align: center; /* Needed for the center alignment inside its 'box' */
  outline: 1px solid lime; /* Just to illustrate the boundaries of the <a>*/
  padding-block: .5em; /* Vertical padding on the nav item */
  padding-inline: 1em; /* Horizontal padding on the nav item */
}


/* Add a change on :hover to <a> elements inside .topnav - we just want to change border colour */
.topnav a:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav">
    <a class="accommodations" href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
    <a class="activities" href="#activities"> Activities </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should definitely try it.This is a Card but this card have color's animated border.in this example I'm using tailwind css.

> cdn link

```
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<!-- Include the Tailwind CSS and Animate.css links in your HTML file, if you haven't already -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.15/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

> css

```
 <style>
    @keyframes neon-border-animation {

        0%,
        100% {
            border-color: #00899e;

        }

        50% {
            border-color: #35c1ff;

        }
    }

    .neon-border {
        animation: neon-border-animation 2s infinite;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00b8d4;
    }



    .card.neon-border:hover {
        border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #b300ff, #ff00ff, #ff6f00);
        border-image-slice: 1;
    }

    footer {
        / position: fixed;/ left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1a202c;
        padding: 1rem;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

> html

```
  <div class="card bg-zinc-700 border-2 border-transparent  shadow-md p-3  neon-border max-w-xs">
    <div class="flex items-center mb-3">
        <div class="rounded-md bg-white p-1 mr-3">
            <img src="images/Rabort.png" alt="artists" class="w-10 h-10 object-cover rounded-md">
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-start">
            <div class="text-left">
                <p class="text-white font-bold">@Devid_Miller</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-left">
                <p class="text-green-500 font-bold text-lg">14.55 ETH</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying my best I hope this is very helpful for you.

Comment: It seems a bit over the top to have to bring in a whole new system (and learn about it) just to achieve recoloring of a line.